# cs-cart send custom value to add-to-cart

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I am working on a project in cs-cart. cs-cart is using smarty PHP template engine and I know that is running on server. Now, for the needs of the website, I would like to calculate inside a product (carpets) according to the size of it the price! So far, I have insert two inputs type texts. The user inserts the size of the carpet (width-height) and I calculate the price of it, using javascript:

```
function func() {
    var metro_timi = 10;
    var x = document.getElementById('mikos');
    var y = document.getElementById('platos');
    var timi = x.value * y.value * metro_timi;
    alert("Η τιμή του χαλιού σας είναι: " + timi + "€");

    document.getElementById("price_metro").value = timi;
}
```

Now, I want this price to send it to the button "Add to cart". Any thoughts, guidance or help would be appreciate! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a hook, while the add to cart is in progress. CS-Cart stores the cart content in the `$_SESSION['cart']` array. The product related things are stored in the `$_SESSION['cart']['products']` array.

The `fn_add_product_to_cart()` function is used to add any product to the cart by core. It has a lot of hooks, you can connect:
`pre_add_to_cart`, `add_product_to_cart_check_price`, `add_to_cart`, `post_add_to_cart`.
You can read more about hooks here: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/addons/hooking/php_hooks.html
You can explore the hook parameters here: http://www.cs-cart.com/api

Comment: ok..I see your point, but I need more help please! I am not very familiar with add-ons, although I have created a simple one. I am working inside the file default_template.tpl (this file is reffering to the products template). According to your links:
I have create the directory app/addons/carpets
Inside this directory I have added the following files:

Comment: addon.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<addon scheme='2.0'>
    <id>carpets</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>carpets</name>
    <description>carpets price</description>
    <priority>100</priority>
</addon>

init.php
<?php
if ( !defined('AREA') ) { die('Access denied'); }

fn_add_product_to_cart(
 'add_product_to_cart'
);
?>

func.php
<?php
if ( !defined('AREA') ) { die('Access denied'); }
function fn_add_to_cart($category_id, $field_list, $get_main_pair, $skip_company_condition, $lang_code)
{
   ...
}
?>
What should I modify, so I can send my new price calculated via javscript?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following hidden input to the template:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="product_data[{$obj_id}][calculated_price]" value="" id="calculated_price_{$obj_id}" />
```

then just add the following line to your javascript code:

```
$('#calculated_price_{$obj_id}').val(timi);
```

As a result, the calculated data will be presented in the $product_data array if the **pre_add_to_cart** hook is used.